# How to read data from ax using business connector through vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I added reference for ax but i don't know how to connect AX to read data through vb.net code,

can any one suggest me samples for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to the [`AxaptaRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsax-2009/developer/aa548861%28v%3dax.50%29) class and call `.next()` on it to read through the results.

There is some c# sample code available that you should be able to convert to VB .NET here: [How to: Read Data Using .NET Business Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsax-2009/developer/cc197126(v=ax.50))

Comment: Yes I have so many examples for C#, can i get sample coding for vb.net?

Comment: i'm new to this and i need to call a class in AX from visual studio 2008 through vb.net

Comment: @SriRanjani You need to call a class but ask a question about how to read data? Calling a class is another approach

Comment: Sorry, Can I know how to call a class from vs through vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

use this kind of method to call ax in vb;

Partial Public Class ValueReport

```
<DataMethod(), AxSessionPermission(SecurityAction.Assert)> Public Shared Function CompanyInfo() As DataTable
    Dim dtCompany As New DataTable
    Try
        Dim record As AxaptaRecordWrapper = SessionManager.GetSession().CreateAxaptaRecord("CompanyInfo")
        record.ExecuteStmt("select * from %1")

        dtCompany.Columns.Add("CompanyName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dtCompany.Columns.Add("CompanyAddress", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

        While (record.Found)
            Dim drCompany As DataRow = dtCompany.NewRow
            drCompany("CompanyName") = record.GetField("Name")
            drCompany("CompanyAddress") = record.GetField("Address")
            dtCompany.Rows.Add(drCompany)
            record.Next()
        End While

        Return dtCompany

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

End Function
```